# Basic Vectors in R (to replace MathCAD)

Tags: r, math, vector

I am learning the basics of vectors and would like, in the end, to be able to use R as a replacement for MathCAD.

Can I please ask to, as an example, calculate the below in R?

[image]

Trying to understand the language from this point of view and, as apparent, I am only just starting.

Many thanks.

Comment: R is vectorized: `sum((20:200)^3 - 3*(20:200)^2)`. You can also assign the vector `n <- 20:200` first and then `sum(n^3 - 3*n^2)`.

Comment: Since MathCAD is an integrated document + calculations environment, you might be interested in Jupyter, which is a notepad-like front end for many computational environments, including R, Octave, Julia, Python, etc etc. See: https://jupyter.org If you are interested in symbolic computation, take a look at Sympy (https://sympy.org) and Maxima (http://maxima.sourceforge.net). There is a Jupyter kernel (back end glue code) for Maxima: https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-jupyter Probably there's one for Sympy too. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(sapply(20: 200, function(n) n^3 - 3*n^2))
```

Comment: No this is not the R way. See @RuiBarradas comment. Always make use of vectorised functions. `sapply` is just a `for` loop in disguise and very inefficient here.